# Drag and drop a created element with JS

Tags: javascript

I've been thinking about this a lot and I'm out of ideas, I can drag and drop the existing element but not the ones I create with the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/1a0fw8c9/1/

```
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const first = document.querySelector('.first')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    first.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div draggable="true" class="item"></div>`)
})

for (const col of cols) {
  col.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  })
  col.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    this.append(e.target)
  })
}

<button>Add</button>

<div class="col first">
  <div draggable="true" class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
```